# How to detect version of MIT Scheme?

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme

Is there a method that can be used to detect the version of MIT Scheme used from within a piece of Scheme code?

For example, I may need a piece of code to determine whether it is being interpreted by MIT Scheme 9.1, or by MIT Scheme 9.2, and act accordingly.

Maybe there exists a procedure (e.g. `(interpreter-version)`) that returns the release number of MIT Scheme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are methods used by some open source projects to detect the version of MIT Scheme:

- Method used by the [SLIB](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/slib/) project (file: [`mitscheme.init`](https://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/slib/slib/mitscheme.init?revision=1.43&view=markup#l27)):

  ```lisp
  (get-subsystem-version-string "Release")
  ```

  Example return value: `"9.2"`
- Method used by the [SLIME](https://common-lisp.net/project/slime/) project (file: [`contrib/swank-mit-scheme.scm`](https://github.com/slime/slime/blob/v2.26.1/contrib/swank-mit-scheme.scm#L64-L66)):

  ```lisp
  (get-subsystem-version "Release")
  ```

  This returns the version numbers in a list. For example, if you are using MIT Scheme version 10.1.10, the return value will be `'(10 1 10)`. Example usage:

  ```lisp
  (if (>= (car (get-subsystem-version "Release"))
          9)
    'do-something-if-version-9-and-above
    'otherwise-do-this-if-below-version-9)
  ```

Caution: The procedures used in this answer are undocumented. `get-subsystem-version` and `get-subsystem-version-string` are both defined in MIT Scheme's [`src/runtime/system.scm`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/mit-scheme.git/tree/src/runtime/system.scm?h=release-11.1#n82) file.

Answer (score 2):

The documented method is `(identify-world)`.

See [mit-scheme-user chapter 2.1](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/stable/mit-scheme-user/Basics-of-Starting-Scheme.html).

Comment: `(identify-world)` does not return the version of MIT Scheme; it only prints the version information. It has an unspecified return value.